# How to install R 3.5.0 on 17.1?

Tags: r

I have downloaded the tar file, but it refuses to make.

Please guide me how to do this please.

Comment: This question asks about R 3.5.0 unlike to other to which it was linked. This question is not a duplicate. As of now none of the answers apply. R 3.5.0 release process for ubuntu can tracked on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/